# Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField' to expected argument type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, oop

I am attempting to append the value from a UITextField into an object and then display the results in a UITableView. The error I get is "Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField' to expected argument type 'Transaction'". I am not sure how to proceed.

```
     class BudgetViewController: UIViewController {


        var budgetData: [Transaction] = [
    Transaction(title: "Rent/Mortgage", dateInfo: "0% out of spent", image: UIImage.gymIcon, amount: 4512),
    Transaction(title: "Utilities", dateInfo: "0% out of spent", image: UIImage.groceriesIcon, amount: 4512)
        ]



   @objc func didTapAddCategory(_ button: UIButton) {
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Choose a category", preferredStyle: .alert)
           alertController.setTitlet(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26), color: UIColor.white)
           alertController.setMessage(font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic", size: 18), color: UIColor.red)
           alertController.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.black)
           
    alertController.addTextField()

       let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { [unowned alertController] _ in
           let answer = alertController.textFields![0]
        
  //error on this line      budgetData.append(answer)
       }

       alertController.addAction(submitAction)
           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.budgetData.count
}


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the text field's `text`, not the text field. Then you need to somehow convert that to your `Transaction` class.

```
if let textFieldText = alertController.textFields![0].text { /// textFieldText is the text of the text field
    let transaction = Transaction(text: textFieldText) /// something like this, I don't know how you make a Transaction
    budgetData.append(transaction)
}
```